# Magento 2 Media Gallery doesn't show any images in 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.1

I installed Magento 2.4.1. All is working fine but the newer feature that Media Gallery does not show any images.

[image: Empty 'Manage Gallery' page]

Is there any other configuration requires for seeing images?
I disabled the old media gallery (see configuration):

[image: Configuration page showing 'Enable Old Media Gallery' = No]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: hi there, try to upload an image to a category or a CMS page, then go back to Content / Media / Manage Gallery and check if you see the images. Please let me know the result.

Comment: yes now its showing the category image which I uploaded...but what about product images?i want to see product images there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research i found the solution for these.

After Set "No" to Enable Old Media Gallery option in Advanced->System section in system configuration

you need to run the following commands:

```
Run in console: php bin/magento media-gallery:sync
Run in console: php bin/magento media-content:sync
```

now images are displaying in media gallery..

Comment: glad to hear this! i also updated my initial answer to include the mention of the 2 consumers in a more visible place.

Answer (score 2):

The [new media gallery](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/cms/media-gallery.html) functionality is supposed to do what the regular media storage did, but with an enhanced UX and design. The images uploaded as category images will be displayed in here, as well as any image uploaded via the content editor (WYSIWYG) as part of an attribute content, a cms block or cms page content or by the page builder.

**For products**, only images which are uploaded in the content of attributes via the content editor (say inside the product description) will show here, and not the images set on the product as values for the base, small, thumbnail images or additional images. This is how the old media storage worked and how the new one does too.

---

***LE***: if you don't see your images from the old storage, make sure you follow the instructions [the official documentation](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/cms/media-gallery.html#enable-the-new-media-gallery), as you will need to start the `media.gallery.synchronization` and `media.content.synchronization` queue consumers for the initialization of the media gallery.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here my problem is that the new category images that I uploaded is only shown in media gallery..the old one category images before upgrade version is not shown there..

Comment: did you run the media gallery queue consumers `media.gallery.synchronization` and `media.content.synchronization`?

Comment: Is this commands or cron run ?

Comment: in the initial documentation, there is a mention *Full functionality for new Media Gallery requires media.gallery.synchronization and media.content.synchronization queue consumers to be started for initial synchronization.* see https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/cms/media-gallery.html#enable-the-new-media-gallery for details

Comment: can you please guide me how to start these 2 queues?

Comment: I just saw you managed to start them and it solved your problem :) good to hear this! please mark the appropriate answer as solution for your question.

Comment: What does "LE" mean?